# How to convert unicode escape sequences to unicode characters in react javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unicode, utf, unicode-escapes

How to convert unicode escape sequences to unicode characters in react javascript.

`Informaci\u00f3n` should get converted to its relevant unicode character string, i.e, `Información`

Comment: that is already seems like a valid "unicode character string" to me, what are you trying todo? are you trying to display the string in html? Can share what you have tried so far?

Comment: What methods have you tried so far? Why didn’t they work for your needs? E.g., have you tried using [decodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent)?

Answer (score 0):

Try the bellow function.

```js
function unicodeToChar(text) {
   return text.replace(/\\u[\dA-F]{4}/gi, 
          function (match) {
               return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(match.replace(/\\u/g, ''), 16));
          });
}

 console.log(unicodeToChar('Informaci\u00f3n'));
```